# How to create a dynamic future for Android app that would autochange after some time?

Tags: android, android-layout, adview

I am trying to make footer dynamic like shown in this image. 
[image: Something similar to one that is inside the red border.]

It should be dynamic and should change after some time. I was thinking of creating the relative layout and using it as a footer. Another approach I thought was about using the advice to show my content. Which should be the most appropriate.

Comment: So you want your footer to show like ads?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "using the advice to show my content". But it does make sense that you could have a footer view at the bottom of your layout, that you rebuild with new content whenever you want to.